# iAD Banner View in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I am implementing the ADbanner view in appdelegate.mm file in cocos2d game. The ads are displaying perfectly but i would like to know where i can implement the iAd banner view delegates. I have added them to appdelegate.mm file but they do not get called.

This is the code to display the ads (they are displayed successfully)

```
iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:iAdView];
```

I now need to implement this

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

I am not using UIViewController as i am using cocos2d(it has scenes)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the delegate of your ADBannerView to your appDelegate:

```
iAdView.delegate = self;
```

Hope this helps.